# Removing tags from a BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am having some difficulty scraping a table from a forum website (with 50 lines per page). My code, as written, works for 95% of the content but adds a table break when a bold or italicized line is present and I do not get the full results

The majority of the pages have the tags like this:

```
<table>
  <td>
    content_1
  </td><td>
    content_2
  </td><td>
    content_3
  </td>
  ...
</table>
```

Though when a bold or italicized phrase is present, for whatever reason a random  tag is added and I only end up with the number of elements up until the tag.

```
<table>
  <td>
    content_1
  </td><td>
      <b><i>content_2</b></i> *</table>*
  </td><td>
    content_3
  </td>
...
</table>
```

I am not sure why this tag shows up (it does not appear when I inspect the element on the webpage).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with this? I have a few ideas but none of them have worked out yet.

- Convert the beautifulsoup object to string then remove the tag and convert back to beautifulsoup - has not quite worked yet, but seems a little excessive and will slow down the program...
- Just skip soup and use pd.read_html - haven't gotten it to work yet.

Or if anyone has suggestions to an alternative approach, that would be appreciated as well. Thanks!

edit - figured it would help if I just added my code. If main block has three examples. First provides no results, second has partial results, and the third is full results.

```
def get_page(URL):
    '''
    INPUT: url
    OUTPUT: pandas dataframe with message board info
    '''
    content = requests.get(URL).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    rows = list(soup.find('table', id="ctl00_CP1_gv"))
    table_lst = []
    for row in rows[2:-2]:
      cell_lst = [cell for cell in list(row)[1:5]]
      table_lst.append(cell_lst)
    return pd.DataFrame(table_lst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url1 = "https://investorshub.advfn.com/Cal-Bay-International-Inc-CBYI-5520/?NextStart=35092"
    url2 = "https://investorshub.advfn.com/Cal-Bay-International-Inc-CBYI-5520/?NextStart=35099"
    url3 = "https://investorshub.advfn.com/Cal-Bay-International-Inc-CBYI-5520/?NextStart=1000"
    df1 = get_page(url1)
    df2 = get_page(url2)
    df3 = get_page(url3)
```

Comment: "...but breaks when a bold or italicized line is present..." Please show the code that breaks, and the error message, if any.

Comment: Apologies, 'break', was the wrong word choice. It just does not provide the full result that others pages provide. I added my code as wells as sample pages...

Comment: That webite is chaotic... Can you clarify what part of those websites you're trying to get, there might be a better tag to go off of?

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty messy... just looking to get the table towards the bottom of the page with like post number, subject, username, date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already noticed that `<b><i>..</b></i>` is out of order, and hence malformed HTML. `html.parser` couldn't handle the job. I've tried `lxml` against your test cases, and it works.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
```

Comment: Looks like that did it. Thank you! I tend to have a bad habbit of always defaulting to html.parser.